# Where can I submit feature requests?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Mojang doesn't often take in community requests for feature to be added to the game. Some current things that were first implemented in mods are:

- Horses
- Commands
- Dual Wielding
- Shaders
- etc.

Are there any ways that users can submit requests that are guaranteed to reach the developers' ears?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes and no.**
From [Mojang's "Where can I submit suggestions?"](https://help.mojang.com/customer/en/portal/articles/920890-where-can-i-submit-suggestions) page:

> Please be aware that we are not actively seeking change or feature
>   requests to Minecraft.
>
> The best place to submit suggestions for Minecraft for PC or
>   Minecraft: Pocket Edition is at [Minecraft Suggestions on Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/minecraftsuggestions). The
>   developers visit sometimes and view highly-rated suggestions. Because
>   the developers can receive hundreds of suggestions a day via Reddit,
>   Twitter and email, they will not be able to view or answer each
>   suggestion.
>
> The development of the console editions of Minecraft generally follow
>   the PC version's development. If you'd like to submit a suggestion,
>   visit your console's corresponding sub-section on the [Minecraft
>   Forums](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums).
>
> Feedback on the Windows 10 Edition can be made [here](https://minecraft.uservoice.com).
>
> If you have an idea for Minecraft for PC, you may instead want to
>   request that a mod developer makes it into a game mod by visiting the
>   [mod request section](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forum/52-requests-ideas-for-mods) of the Minecraft Forums.